# Xamarin.Android: How to stop Visual Studio from removing the previous version of the app before deploying

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm migrating an Android app written in Java to Xamarin.

The old app (Java) stores some data in the AccountManager and a SQLite DB and I'm looking to migrate that over to a new format when existing users install the new app (Xamarin) as an update so they won't loose their existing data

I'm looking to test the migration code, so I installed a version of the old app on a physical device and then I deployed the new version (a version higher) to the same device but each time I do that, Visual Studio removes the older app and before installing the new app which makes it impossible to debug the migration code (the AccountManager entry which contains data is nuked the moment the older version is uninstalled before launch).

Some things I did try before posting here:

- I've enabled "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96902/android-app-keeps-getting-uninstalled)
- Enabled Fast Deployment

Nothing seems to work - I just need the data preserved between deployments so my migration code has a chance to run.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac if that's relevant

Comment: Which mode did you use? Debug or release . If you deploy your app in debug mode . VS and AS will have different key store .

Comment: I've gone into Project Options and specified a keystore and password to use for release and debug configurations (under "Android Package Signing")

I've run this in Debug and Release mode. It does not seem to make a difference.  I've even tried generating a signed release APK and tried "adb -r app.apk" in the hope of simulating an upgrade but yet the new app seems to be nuking the AccountManager data even outside of VS

Comment: What type of Android are you using? mine was Android Q with MIUI v.10.2 and the OS had an optimization feature on the developer settings that when disabled, it stopped "reinstalling" the app

Comment: Bog standard Samsung S6 running Android 6.0 and a Pixel 2 running Pie. I don't see anything under Developer Settings can sound like what you described.

Comment: mine was called "MIUI Optimization", since i turn that off, i don't have any deploying issues, i guess it was just an specific case for me

Comment: has anyone figuredout the solution. . . . i am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two different things :

When deploying, Visual Studio never updates but uninstalls, then reinstalls the application. Jonathan Prior explained it [in 2017](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/27/27266/bug.html#c12) and it is still the case today. As far as I know there is no way to change that, but this is usually not a problem because you can choose to keep the data (VS uses then `adb uninstall -k`).

On the other hand, if you build a release APK, and install it with `adb install -r`, then you are using the exact same update mechanism that will be used to deploy your app on users devices. Your migration code will be executed, if not it just means that it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Installing a *signed* (release apk) Xamarin app on top of the Java app using adb install -r still erases AccountManager data. What I can't explain is why this does not seem to happen when I upgrade the Java app with the same Java app (a version higher) using the same adb command. It appears that the AccountManager data is only overwritten when the APK generated using Xamarin is used. This begs the question: What's so different with the APK xamarin generates that's causing this?

Comment: I would start by comparing the full manifests. Android Studio : *merged manifest* tab, Visual Studio : `obj/Release/*/android/AndroidManifest.xml`. Alternatively you can extract it from APKs : `apkanalyzer manifest print some.apk`

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can probably just publish a beta version to playstore and download it from there

What I think you can do is (though I never tried it myself) you can change the applicationId of one app, so both will be present in your phone at the same time. Then since the underlying file structure of both app should be same, you can copy the storage content of previous version to your current version

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mynewversion"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0001"
    }
```

Comment: I'm well past this point - the new app (xamarin) as the same application id and a version code that +1 higher than the older (java) app so it should replace the app once it's upgraded. Both apps are also signed with the same keystore. The problem i'm still having is running the new app from VS literally uninstalls the older app first which then removes all data associated with it. Need a way to simulate an upgrade so i could debug the migration code.

Comment: Then  I can't think of any other way than uploading a beta version to playstore. Of course, you won't be able to debug it but at least you can check if your app has the intended behavior

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this could be using the [Beta](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/) tool from Crashlytics, as follow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46155893/4855062